# Formatting paper for submission

Tags: paper-submission

I'm submitting my paper to Quantitative Finance (instruction to authors [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=rquf20)). The structure of the paper should be:

> Manuscripts should be compiled in the following order: title page (including Acknowledgements as well as Funding and grant-awarding bodies); abstract; keywords; main text; references; appendices (as appropriate); table(s) with caption(s) (on individual pages); figure caption(s) (as a list).

I'm a bit confused by this requirement. Does anyone know how a title page is meant to look like? All the papers I've seen simply have Title up top, followed by authors, keywords and abstract. The same goes for figure captions as a list. Did they mean itemize all the captions?!

Comment: Look at any paper they have published.

Comment: @buffy Looks like a journal that does the layout for the authors. Papers are submitted as word file or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a journal where you don't do the final layout yourself, but rather submit a word document (or similar).

The style guide is unfortunately down.... But generally it works like this:

The "title page" contains all the information that will be added at the appropriate positions later. For example, just write, without much formatting:

```
Title: Paper of fancy stuff.
Running title: #fancystuff

Authors:
A. Awoman
B. Bman
C. Computerguy

Affiliations
Institute of Awesomeness

Acknowledgements:
We thank Dr X and Dr Y for doing all the work and the technical support group of Institute of Awesomeness for putting it together.

Word count (* especially when they have word limits)
Abstract: 249
Introduction: 1234
Discussion: 2345


Funding: co-authors grandma
```

The figure captions should indeed be on a separate page, as a list (without the figures):

```
Figure 1: This is Figure 1. We show stuff.

Figure 2: Fancy stuff. Very nice.

Figure 3: Other stuff. Somewhat nice.
```

Tables should come on separete pages, not in text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm curious as to why they offer a latex template that looks like a regular journal paper, but ask you to re-order it such that it doesn't look like a regular paper.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when I write a paper for a conference or a journal, I download their template and start adding my content into the empty template. Things invariably fall into the right place. Even if you have written the paper in another template, it is a good idea to open both the documents and copy section by section into the new template.

So look for the templates e.g. http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/rqufLatex.zip
and use start using it.

As suggested by @Buffy above, you should consider looking at published papers. I think they are trying to stress upon the fact that in your title page, which is nothing but the first page of your paper, you must include acknowledgements, and other information properly. So title page which is the first page will also include your paper sections.

Comment: Correct.  You do not need "keywords" on a page by themselves.  Just put them after the abstract and before the main text.  The order given here is for your submission; in the final published paper the order may be different.  In your submission, the figure captions will be listed at the end, but in the published paper the figure captions will be adjacent to the figures.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another reason I was confused is because their template looks just like a regular paper (without all the weird ordering) and captions in the right place